# How to set up foreignkey using xamarin mvvm

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

***Tools:*** I am using Xamarin forms MVVM and SQLite-Net-pcl

***Error*** cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'string'

how to set up basic ForeignKey with different names for primarykey and foreignkey? I am getting an error on line

```
[ForeignKey(typeof(ProductModel))]
```

ProductModel class

```
*class ProductModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductURL { get; set; }
}
```

ordermodel class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Sqlite;

class OrderModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(typeof(ProductModel))]
    public int ProdcutId_FK { get; set; }
    
    public int OrderQty { get; set; }
}*
```

Comment: you need to use SQLIte.Net Extensions for FK support - https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/src/master/

Comment: is this a nuget i can install?

Comment: if you read the docs it explains how to install it

Comment: just install it and not working... I think ill just move to different database. but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class OrderModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    
    public int OrderQty { get; set; }
   
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ProductId ))]
    [InverseProperty("Orders")]
    public ProductModel Product { get; set; }
  
}

class ProductModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductURL { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(OrderModel.Product))]
    public virtual ICollection<OrderModel> Orders{ get; set; }
}
```